# docker-compose build --no-cache not working

Tags: docker, cache, docker-compose

I made some updates on a Dockerfile for one of the services, but the changes are not reflecting, when running `docker-compose build`, not even with `--no-cache` option.

I added two two parameter before running `pip install -f requirements.txt`, but they are not executed at any time: it goes directly to the requirements step.

```
$ docker-compose build --no-cache
mongo uses an image, skipping
postgres uses an image, skipping
elasticsearch uses an image, skipping
Building nucleo
Step 1/9 : FROM python:3.6
 ---> 2bb3204ab1d1
Step 2/9 : COPY core/ /container_core/
 ---> cc1eadcb80a3
Step 3/9 : WORKDIR /container_core
 ---> Running in e8afa25b9c9a
Removing intermediate container e8afa25b9c9a
 ---> f9b928dee6f5
Step 4/9 : RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in 84f474edb526
^CERROR: Aborting.
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
services:
    mongo:
        image: "mongo:4.0.5"
        container_name: compose_mongo
        restart: always
        environment:
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=mongo
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=mongopass
        ports:
            - "27017:27017"
    core:
        build:
            context: /home/ivanleoncz/git/core
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        container_name: compose_core
        depends_on:
            - mongo
        env_file:
            - .env
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.6
COPY core/ /container_core/
WORKDIR /container_core
# must run before requirements
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install urllib3=1.20
# then, run the requirements
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python3", "manage.py", "makemigrations", "app1"]
CMD ["python3", "manage.py", "makemigrations", "app2"]
CMD ["python3", "manage.py", "makemigrations", "app3"]
CMD ["python3", "manage.py", "migrate"]
CMD ["python3", "manage.py", "runserver"]
```

I'm using docker-compose 1.21.2, with Ubuntu 18.04.2.

How can I guarantee that `docker-compose` is not using an old version of my Dockerfile, even though I'm describing that I want to perform the build, without any cache (`--no-cache`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was running `docker-compose build --no-cache` from a different directory  from the one which is defined on the tag `context` on **docker-compose.yaml**.

```
core:
    build:
        context: /home/ivanleoncz/git/core
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

In this different directory, I was updating my Dockerfile, and on the context directory, **I had an outdated the Dockerfile**.

Due to the context which was defined, the `/home/ivanleoncz/git/core/Dockerfile` was considered during the `docker-compose build --no-cache` process, and not the Dockerfile from my current directory.